What is the conservation form of this Euler equation?
We have a Euler equation:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} L_1 + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} L_2 - L_3 = 0
$$
where
$$
L_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi_t} L, \qquad 
L_2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi_x} L, \qquad
L_3 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} L
$$
Further take
$$
\varphi = \Phi(\theta, X, T; \epsilon) \\
\theta = \epsilon^{-1} \Theta(X,T), \qquad X = \epsilon x, T = \epsilon t \\
\nu(X,T) = -\omega(X,T) = \Theta_T, \qquad k(X,T) = \Theta_X
$$
so the Euler equation becomes:
$$
\nu \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \theta} + \epsilon \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial T}
+ k \frac{\partial L_2}{\partial \theta} + \epsilon \frac{\partial L_2}{\partial X}
- L_3 = 0
$$
The textbook said the conservation form of this Euler equation is:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} [(\nu L_1 + k L_2) \Phi_\theta - 
L(\varphi_x, \varphi_t, \varphi)] + \epsilon \frac{\partial}{\partial T} (\Theta_\theta L_1)
+ \epsilon \frac{\partial}{\partial X}(\Theta_\theta L_2) = 0
$$
My question is how to derive this form?
